# Cayley graphs obtained for different generating elements with the same orders in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, combinatorial-group-theory, cayley-graphs

When we consider the finite group $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime, $p>2$, the set with the pair of elements $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ can generate the group. Moreover, a set $\{(1,0),(1,2)\}$ can also generate the group. Hence, there are many pairs of elements which can act as generating elements.

Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_q$. A set $\{t,s\}$, where $|t|=p$ and $|s|=q$ is a minimal generating element set for some $p,q$ and $\phi$ values (Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes, $p,q>2$).

Under a certain $\phi, p, q$, the $t,s$ elements were,

$t=((1,0),0),\,\, s=((0,0),1)$

These generating elements can be used to draw a Cayley graph of the group.

However, if I take $t=((3,0),0)$ and draw the graph (under the same $\phi$. Suppose $\phi$ is defined using a general formula like, $\phi(t^i)=t^{i+1}$. (This is only an example). Then I can apply $\phi(t)$ to any $t$ value), the graph is the same as earlier graph if I forget the vertex lables.

Then can I bring an argument here, that I can use any element of order $p$ as $t$ and any element of order $q$ as $s$ in the generating set?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: To do the Cayley graph, and I'm new to this, but it seems like you would need generators for $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$.  This requires _two_ generators, at least.  Together with the generator for $\Bbb Z_q$, that makes three.  You only have two.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisCuster no for some groups of above type (i.e. for some $p,q$ values) we can have only two element generating sets. :)

Comment: Oh ok, my intuition was off here.  I guess that makes sense, especially since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.  For instance $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_q$ only needs one generator.

Comment: Ok. :)  @ChrisCuster, what do you think about my argument? Suppose we have two generating elements as above mentioned or three generating elements, then do you think I can choose any two elements of order $p$, (in a way it'll generate $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ subgroup) and any element of order $q$ as the generating elements and use the given function $\phi$?

Comment: My intuition is that you would need one of order $p$ and one of order $q$, and then use the action.  But I may be off again.  Right.  I saw your edit.  Probably.

Comment: There is something wrong here. The map $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $C_q$ to ${\rm Aut}(C_p^2)$, so it is defined on powers of $s$ rather than on powers of $t$.

Comment: I guess instead "$|q|=q$" there should be "$|s|=q$".

Comment: Yes, @DerekHolt but the $\phi$ which is defined based on $s$, has to be applied on elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, so with in the bracket I think elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ are coming, am I correct? :) If I add more details:-

Comment: As an example, consider the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$, where $p \, (>3)$ is a prime. Let $S=\{s,t\}$ be a generating set where $|s|=3, |t|=p$. The action of $s$ on $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ can be defined by a linear transformation $T$ on $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, by $T(v)= s^{-1}vs$. Let, $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$ and let $u=T(t)=s^{-1}ts$. Now,

Comment: 1. Since, $|s|=3$, $T^3=I$ and so, $m(x)$ divides $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: 2. Since, $|[G,G]|=p^2$, 1 is not an eigenvalue of $T$, where $[G,G] \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: 3. Because $<s,t>=G$, $u=T(t) \notin <t>$, so the minimal polynomial of $T$ has degree 2 (and $\{t,u\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$)

Comment: Then we can get that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^2+x+1$. With respect to the basis $\{t,u\}$,
$T(t^iu^j)=s^{-1}t^iu^js=t^{-j}u^{i-j}$. i.e. $T(i,j)=(-j,i-j)$.

Here, we can see that $T$ can be defined in terms of $i,j$ and by multiplying elements of $G$ by $s,t$ under this $T$, we can generate the Cayley graph. So here, if I choose $t=((0,1),0), u=((1,0),0)$ and $s=((0,0),1)$ and find the elements by considering the above $T(t^iu^j)=t^{-j}u^{i-j}$, then I can get a Cayley graph.

Comment: If I choose $t$ (say, $t=((0,3),0)$ to be some other element of order $p$ and get other suitable values for $u,s$ also, it seems that I can get the same Cayley graph if I forget the vertex labelling (i.e $((0,0),0), ((0,0),1), $ etc.). because suppose, from the identity vertex, by multiplying by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t,0)$, and then if you multiply again by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t^3,0)$ etc. then this is the way edges are connected for whatever the $t$ value.

So then there can be many elements that can be chosen in place of $t$, $u$ and $s$. Am I right?

Comment: (Actually I should have mentioned $\phi(t^iu^j)$ something like that instead of saying $\phi(t^i)$ in the question. Thanks a lot @AlexRavsky I have edited the question now. :)

Comment: I guess instaed “by multiplying by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t,0)$, and then if you multiply again by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t^3,0)$ etc”. Should be something like “by multiplying by $t$ it goes to vertex $t=((0,3),0)$, and then if you multiply again by $t$ it goes to vertex $t^2$ etc”.

Comment: Yes, @AlexRavsky I have only written it as a sketch without considering the actual values, to express my idea. If I take it really, by multiplying by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t,0)$, and then if you multiply again by $t$ it goes to vertex $(t^2,0)$ etc. When $t=((0,1),0)$, $(t^2,0)=((0,2),0)$ and when $t=((0,3),0)$, $(t^2,0)=((0,6),0)=((0,1),0)$ if $p=5$. Anyhow, it keeps the pattern for whatever the $t$ we choose, and if we label the vertices in terms of variables $t^i, u^j, s^k$ we get the same graph, even for different choices of $t,u,s$

Comment: When we use GAP to compute a minimum generating set it usually gives elements like $((0,1),0),((1,0),0),((0,0),1)$. That's why I'm asking to clarify, whether it's ok to choose other values like $((0,3),0)$ when choosing the generating elements manually, @AlexRavsky and

Comment: @DerekHolt what do you think?

Comment: You are assuming that the action on $C_p^2$ defined by $\phi(s)$ (i.e. conjugation by $s$ in the semidirect product) is irreducible. So yes you can choose any nontrivial element of $C_p^2$ as your generator. The minimal polynomial of the action will be the same for any such element. You could also use some power of $s$ like $s^2$ as your other generator, but that might have a different minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much @DerekHolt :)

Comment: You can write the above comment as an answer to my question @DerekHolt it is the answer that I required So I invite and request you to write it as an answer :) Thanks. :)

Comment: OK I'll do that later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarized idea of the answer of above question:

For a group $G = (\mathbb{Z}_p \times  \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_q$,

$\phi: \mathbb{Z}_q \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) $

defines the semidirect product. Let $S=\{s,t\}$, where $|s|=q$ and $|t|=p$ denote an irredundant generating set of $G$ and let $\{t,u\}$, where $|u|=p$ be a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. ($\phi_s(t) = s^{-1}ts =u$).

For an element $\phi(s)=\phi_s \in Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, in defining the automorphism,

$\phi_s(t^{i} u^{j})$ using the generating elements $t,u \in \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, we can choose different candidates of order $p$ as $t$ and $u$, chosen appropriately.

i.e. as an example,

$t=((0,1),0), u=((1,0),0)$ is one choice, but also $t=((0,3),0), u=((1,0),0)$ can be another choice. Likewise, there can be several choices for the generating elements.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt I added a summarized description since the bounty is close to get expired. I've not tested bounty offers before, so I'm not sure how it's operating, so I added the summary. But please be kind enough to add your answer/edit my answer as required. Hope it's ok. Thank you very much.